# Solr pivot faceting or hierarchical faceting, overall limit

Tags: solr, lucene, facet

A Solr pivot faceting query returns a tree of facets such as:

```
      "cat,popularity,inStock":[{
      "field":"cat",
      "value":"electronics",
      "count":14,
      "pivot":[{
          "field":"popularity",
          "value":6,
          "count":7,
          "pivot":[
              {
                  "field":"inStock",
                  "value":true,
                  "count":5
              }, 
              {
                  "field":"inStock",
                  "value":false,
                  "count":2
              }]},
          {
          "field":"popularity",
          "value":1,
          "count":4,
          "pivot":[
              {
                  "field":"inStock",
                  "value":true,
                  "count":3
              }, 
              {
                  "field":"inStock",
                  "value":false,
                  "count":1
              }]
          ]}]
```

Is there a way to specify a limit on the number of returned leaves (i.e. the number of objects with "field":"inStock" in the example above, which is 4)?

Note that this is not the same as defining a limit on the individual facets, such as "f.popularity.facet.limit", which only limit the degree of the facet tree internal nodes.

Thanks

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: See the edited question, with an example.